# Sysprep - Win 10 1903 - language packs

Tags: windows, sccm, sysprep, mdt

Microsoft in their infinite wisdom appear to have changed their approach to multi-lingual support in Windows 10. Whereas a normal user can install language packs via the language settings, this breaks Sysprep, as the user context appears to be used for the appx packages and not provisioning for the system. In 1809 and previous, we'd download the Language Pack ISO from Volume Licensing and use DISM to install the languages, but Microsoft has neglected to release this so far neither can I see any comms about when it might be out.

Can anyone provide any information on the method of injecting languages in 1903 for gold image deployment across multiple countries? Hopefully, they documented this somewhere and I've yet to find it...

Additionally, we have SCCM, so this is another option for an answer if you only have a solution via that.

Comment: Perhaps the theory is that you don't need to inject language packs into the image any more because the end user can now install the appropriate language pack themselves?

Comment: ...and that philosophy definitely works when the user has admin rights. In an enterprise environment with (somewhat) tight permissions, it seems to fall flat.

Comment: @Pres, I thought you didn't need admin rights?

Comment: It might be that if MS Store is locked down via GPO, administrator is required to re-ignite the store in order to deliver the content. That's a guess

Comment: I chatted with a "Microsoft Expert" who told me they didn't have an official date yet for the 1903 language packs to be released, and then told me September!

Comment: mu_windows_10_language_pack_version_1903_x86_arm64_x64_dvd is out

Comment: Thanks for your comments, all. Looks like it was just a case of waiting. Somewhat troublesome if you're not experienced enough to know about the delays already.